# SELECT inside pivot incorrect

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

SSMS is highlighting that something is wrong on the line **FOR urlsByFilm.Media_Type_ID IN...**

```
BEGIN
    SELECT urlsByFilm.Film_ID, urlsByFilm.Media_Type_ID, urlsByFilm.Media_File_Name
    FROM [dbo].[Film_Media_Item] urlsByFilm
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(urlsByFilm.Media_File_Name) 
        FOR urlsByFilm.Media_Type_ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT Media_Type_ID FROM [dbo].[Film_Media_Item])
    ) AS pivot

    WHERE API_ID in (@API_IDs)
END
```

I cannot run this, can you help?

Answer (score 0):

you can't have SQL expression in the `IN` clause, you need to specify the values.

```
    MAX(urlsByFilm.Media_File_Name) 
    FOR urlsByFilm.Media_Type_ID IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT Media_Type_ID FROM [dbo].[Film_Media_Item])
```

You need to use dynamic SQL to achieve what you are doing.

your query would like this, with dynamic SQL

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(2000)
SELECT  @cols = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT 
                                '],[' + Media_Type_ID
                        [dbo].[Film_Media_Item]
                        ORDER BY '],[' + Media_Type_ID
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                      ), 1, 2, '') + ']'

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000)

SET @query = N'SELECT Media_File_Name, '+
    @cols +'
    FROM
    (SELECT urlsByFilm.Film_ID, urlsByFilm.Media_Type_ID, urlsByFilm.Media_File_Name
    FROM [dbo].[Film_Media_Item] urlsByFilm)p
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(urlsByFilm.Media_File_Name) 
        FOR urlsByFilm.Media_Type_ID IN ( '+
        @cols +' )
    ) AS pvt
    WHERE API_ID in (@API_IDs)'

EXECUTE(@query)
```

Comment: That @cols doesnt make sense, but I think I get the idea.